# Can't download apps after changing Apple ID password

Tags: apple-id

I changed my Apple ID password, after that I can't download apps, even free apps. It says need verification of payment info. Now what to do...?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `AppStore > Store (top menu) > View my account` and check your payment info - you might have a link there that will help you reauthenticate payment info. If that won't help - change something in payment info, that should trigger reauthenticate process.